# Expected wrong argument type - Swift 4

Tags: swift

I have a class "Locations" that contains an array of the structure "Location" and some functions. When I try to call a function from locations, I am expected an argument I did not specify (or I did not realize I did). I want to have something of type "Location" as argument.

This is what I am told I should complete the call with:
[image]

But this is how the class/function looks like:

```
class Locations {
    var locations: [Location] = []

    func addLocationIfSignificant(loc: Location) {
        if locations.isEmpty {
            locations.append(loc)
            return
        }
        // do some other stuff
    }
}
```

Definition of `significantLocations`:

```
var significantLocations = Locations.self
```

Comment: Show your declaration for `significantLocations`.

Comment: How do you define `significantLocations`?

Comment: I have updated the post. Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your declaration `var significantLocations = Locations.self` is saying “treat the variable `significantLocations` as a proxy for the type `Locations`”

This makes sense from your error message. You are essentially trying to run the function against the type `Locations` not an instance of `Locations`.

Change your declaration to ...

```
var significantLocations = Locations()
```

And it will fix your problem.

If you want more info as to why your error was showing what it was showing then let me know and I’ll provide it.

Comment: Thank you, it makes sense. I was trying to make an instance, but I am not very familiar with the syntax.

Comment: @IoanaSurduBob no worries. I recommend downloading the free Swift book from Apple to read up on some of the basic syntax.